# Create unique and one time use link to reset password

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

This is my first ASP.net application using c#. As far as the question arrives to have secure process to set password if user forgot his/her password, I need to send email on registered email id of user which contains unique and one time use link which will open a page having two fields say 'Password' and 'Confirm Password' and button 'Submit' to set new password for that user. I have a code fr sending email but the question is how to create a unique and one time use link of page to do so. If you need any code sample from me I will share it. Thanks.

Comment: `Identity` in ASP has a implemented feature for reseting password - you can find some resources on the internet. If you don't use `Identity`, the pattern is pretty simple: when user request a password reset, create random guid, store it in the database (f.e in user table) then send it to you user via e-mail.  You can put. f.e in a link to reset page, where some paramter (f.e. `token`) in query string equals the generated guid. Next , just do a validate - compare a guid from query string and database.

Answer (score 2):

create a guid and save in the database against the user and create a flag for the guid, and pass the same guid in the link you are sending, use the guid to get back the user and change the password and flag as the link being already used. Hope this helps

Comment: You could also simply delete the row with the guid once it has been used. Reduces checking for existence and already used to only checking for existence

Comment: Yeah, i agree with you it will definitely reduce the search overhead, i always keep the records for reference, @Übercoder

Comment: Hello sir, While I am using same idea, I created a unique link using guid and send it through mail but  I don't know how to send user_id linked with link and while loading link page how to detect that user_id... I think if it is solve thing will work out.

Comment: If I am unable to detect user and the guid code save across him the thing will does not making any sense.

Comment: @DipakAkhade, use the guid alone in the link, get the guid id from the request querystring and check the value in the database where the guid is unutilised to get the user_id, the guid will be unique so you dont have to worry about duplication. Now use this user_id to update the password.

Comment: Can you send me code please. Because I am understanding what are you saying but don't know how to access guid code after loading page.